# Resizing Iframes in Facebook Applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

So it looks like Facebook has removed the [page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Resizable_IFrame) referencing how to resize iframe apps except [this one](http://apps.facebook.com/wzhu_public_resize/) which includes a 404'ed js file.

All of the examples I am finding online either reference the aforementioned missing javascript file or they simply do not work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean setting a specific size statically or dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize).

EDIT: Lovely, doesn't seem to work.